# Koa router not seeing post body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, koa.js

Testing koa.js and fetch on the client side. I am trying to post some data on the server. I am getting undefined with the code below. I am unsure why.

I have inspected `this`, `this.request`, `this.req`, etc and I cannot find my data from the client req?

**Server**

```
import koaRouter from 'koa-router'

// Post route
router.post('/api/upload', function *(next) {
  console.log('UPLOAD WORKS', this.req.body)
  this.status = 200
})

app
  .use(bodyParser())
  .use(router.routes())
  .use(router.allowedMethods())
```

The console gives me undefined.

**Client**

```
fetch('/api/upload', {
  method: 'post',
  body: 'Hello'
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response)
}).catch(function(err) {
  // Error :(
});
```

Comment: Could be duplicated of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31504814/koa-router-and-post)

Comment: I came across that. I was still missing my data. I am thinking its because of fetch() maybe.

Comment: If you found some posts about your question, please include those in the text and tell why are not an answer in your case.

Comment: I get an empty {} obj

Comment: Ok, on your client fetch you should consider to use a 'FormData' object to wrap your string. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data) an example.

Comment: Thanks, but still empty. Hmm I am playing around.

Answer (score -1):

You should change your client fatch to use a 'FormData' object to wrap the string.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('json', 'Hello');

fetch('/api/upload', {
  method: 'post',
  body: formData
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response)
}).catch(function(err) {
  // Error :(
});
```